# Why is my floating action button not floating on a screen I created>

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi kindly help me again with this, my floating action button is not displaying over all the elements I put but it is at the bottom of the page. I checked the boiler plate of flutter when you create a project its the same but mine wont position properly.

> Note: I searched about this but and found out about `Stack` and `Extended` but I dont exactly know where to put them. Thank you!

here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/afterintroducing.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/discount_carousel.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/header_carousel.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/introducing_vmembership.dart';

class NavHome extends StatefulWidget {
  // static final String id = 'homepage';
  NavHome({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavHomeState createState() => _NavHomeState();
}

class _NavHomeState extends State<NavHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                "Explore V!",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
            HeaderCarousel(),
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                "Discount",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
              ),
            ),
            DiscountCarousel(),
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                "Introducing V Membership Plus",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4.0),
              child: Text(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
              ),
            ),
            VmembershipPlus(),
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                "Lorem Ipsum",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4.0),
              child: Text(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            AfterIntroducing(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
              child: FlatButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                color: Colors.blue,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  "LOREM IPSUM",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50.0,
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your FloatingActionButton outside the body, but inside the scaffold widget.

The FloatingActionButton will have a default behaviour, if you add it to the Scaffold property floatingActionButton like,

```
class _NavHomeState extends State<NavHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
         body: Your_Widget_Here(),
         floatingActionButton : FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FloatActionButton should put in the same level of app bar or body in Scaffold:

```
class _NavHomeState extends State<NavHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
         body: Container(),
         FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
    );
  }
}
```

Check the example in [flutter youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw) or [flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/) for every widget, you will know how to put them in widget tree.

You can also check [FloatingActionButton class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/afterintroducing.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/discount_carousel.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/header_carousel.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Widgets/introducing_vmembership.dart';

class NavHome extends StatefulWidget {
  // static final String id = 'homepage';
  NavHome({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavHomeState createState() => _NavHomeState();
}

class _NavHomeState extends State<NavHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

        body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                "Explore V!",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
            HeaderCarousel(),
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                "Discount",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
              ),
            ),
            DiscountCarousel(),
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                "Introducing V Membership Plus",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4.0),
              child: Text(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
              ),
            ),
            VmembershipPlus(),
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                "Lorem Ipsum",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4.0),
              child: Text(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            AfterIntroducing(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
              child: FlatButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                color: Colors.blue,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  "LOREM IPSUM",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50.0,
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton :  FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
           onPressed: () {},
       )
    );
  }
}
```